# Keeping NAs in grepl command

Tags: r, na, grepl

I need to keep NAs in my variables.

I have a variable with names, some have upper and some mixed cases. I want to generate a variable which defines the following
name with at least one lower cases = 1
name with only upper cases = 0
NA =
(I want to keep it, because I need to make my regressions with non-response)

My code is the following, but I don't know how to implement the `NA` command.

```
df <- grepl("[a-z]", x$variable)
```

Comment: Please post sample test data and corresponding expected output.

Comment: So basically you want to make `df` as `NA` where `x$variable` is `NA`. `df[is.na(x$variable)] <- NA`

Answer (score 2):

You could use `ifelse` and `is.na` to check for NA first and only use the result of `grepl` for values other than NA:

```
df <- ifelse(is.na(x$variable), NA, grepl("[a-z]", x$variable))
```

Answer (score 1):

The function below returns

- `TRUE` if any character is a lower case letter;
- `FALSE` if no character is a lower case letter;
- `NA` if the input is `NA`.

All arguments of `grepl` can be used, with the same results except for the behavior in the presence of `NA`'s.

```
na_grepl <- function(pattern, x, ...){
  y <- grepl(pattern, x, ...)
  is.na(y) <- is.na(x)
  y
}

x <- c("abc", "ABc", "ABC", NA)
na_grepl("[a-z]", x)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE    NA
```